# WinAPI - Need CreateThread()'s thread function to send additional parameters

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I need the CreateThread() function's thread function, processClient(LPVOID) in my case, to accept additional parameters when it creates the thread (ie: processClient(LPVOID,someADTorARRAY)).

My current code:

```
...function declaration
DWORD WINAPI processClient(LPVOID lpParam){
    ...do stuff with socket
}

...in main
CreateThread(
                NULL,                       // don't inherit handle
                0,                          // use default size for the executable
                processClient,
                (LPVOID)ClientSocket,       // thread data
                0,                          // run right away
                &i );
```

Comment: Unrelated, but do pay special attention to the remarks section of [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx): *"A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the _beginthreadex and _endthreadex functions for thread management rather than CreateThread and ExitThread"*. And *should* should really read *must*.

Comment: @IInspectable: Must *if* it uses certain functions. Many of those functions (e.g., `strtok`), however, are better to just avoid anyway though. The only real problem is that the only documentation of which functions to avoid is the source to `_beginthread[ex]`.

Comment: @Jerry What about `errno`, or the locale? Both of which are controlled per thread. I suppose the list of CRT functions that can safely be called from a thread that hasn't been properly initialized is much shorter than the list of functions that cannot. Technically you are right. Your implied advice is wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable: I'm not advising anything. I'm merely commenting (thus the placement in a comment). The "safe" list is actually quite a bit longer than you seem to think though. In case you care to get into the details, `tidtable.c` in the crt source code is a reasonable starting point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a struct with all the parameters and then pass the pointer to that.

```
struct ClientParams
{
    socket sock;
    someADT adt;
    ...
}

ClientParams params = new ClientParams();
CreateThread(..., (LPVOID)params, ...);
```

Comment: It isn't, strictly speaking. If you make the object local and pass it to your thread function, the calling function may return, causing the object to go out of scope and causing your pointer to be invalid when you try to access it in the other thread.

Comment: @shawna, if your main thread is going to wait for the child to exit, then it can pass local/stack objects. Otherwise it is best to allocated the memory, and have the child thread free it.